# Sorting a column with alphanumeric data and numbers separated by commas

Tags: postgresql, sorting, numbers, alphanumeric

Could everyone explain me how I could sort out the following column?.

```
description
3
5
1,2
10
6,7,8,9
2_L
1_L
3_R
1_R
4_L
3_L
2_R
4
3/2_R
3/1_R
```

the result should be:

```
1,2
3
4
5
6,7,8,9
1_L
2_L
3_L
4_L
1_R
2_R
3_R
3/1_R
3/2_R
```

Comment: Where should `1,3,1` be sorted? Or  `6,8,9`? Or `3_A`?

Comment: Nope, the information related to  rows (e.g. 1,2,3 or 3,2,1 or 1,3,2) should not be organized, just the column must show a sequence  as it was shown in the description of the solution. I would like to see an optional solution  In case it is possible to sort out the rows aswell, but thats not an emergency.

Comment: I'm sorry, i've forgotten to say that I am working with" POSTGRES". Additionally, I'd be happy to read a solution in php aswell =)